# overflow in implicit constant conversion warning while assigning string size(string::npos) to an integer variable

Tags: c++, gcc, warnings, integer-overflow

How to get rid of the the warning below?

```
size_t filesize = getFilesize(strLogFileName.c_str());
// Open file
int fd = open(strLogFileName.c_str(), O_RDONLY, 0);
assert(fd != -1);
// Execute mmap
char* mmappedData =
    (char *) mmap(NULL, filesize, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_POPULATE, fd, 0);
assert(mmappedData != NULL);
string strFileContent(mmappedData);

// warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion
int pos, lpos = string::npos;
```

What changes could be required in the code to fix this warning, rather than ignoring this warning?

Comment: What about suppressing warning message? (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

Comment: To which line is the error pointing?

Comment: int pos,lpos = string::npos;

Comment: Not C code - tag removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string::npos` is of type `size_t`. Assigning a `size_t` to an `int` can cause an overflow during conversion. Fix it as follows:

```
size_t pos;
size_t lpos = string::npos;
```

Or, as suggested by user2079303 you can use either `string::size_type` or, more conveniently, `auto` if you want to support strings with custom allocators.

Comment: For extra pedantry, you may want to use `string::size_type` instead of `size_t` in order to support strings with custom allocators.

Comment: @user2079303 Thanks, worked your suggestion into the answer for completeness.

Answer (score 4):

Use the **correct** type:

```
size_t pos, lpos = std::string::npos;
```

or `auto`. We don't index standard containers with `int`s, nor anything `signed`. And note that `pos` is uninitialized.